# Previously uploaded image remoced on record update in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a weird behaviour on my edit form using sonata admin bundle. I have a field called worksheet which accepts PDF upload. The files upload fine but then the field gets blanked whenever an update is made to a field. How can I prevent this behaviour?

I created the listener below to upload files according to the latest symfony cookbook here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\UNOE;
use AppBundle\Entity\COE;
use AppBundle\FileUploader;

class SheetUploadListener
{
    private $uploader;

    public function __construct(FileUploader $uploader)
    {
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    private function uploadFile($entity)
    {
        // upload only works for InspectionSheet entities
        if($entity instanceof UNOE) {

          $file = $entity->getWorksheet();
          // only upload new files
          if (!$file instanceof UploadedFile) {
              return;
          }
          $fileName = $this->uploader->upload($file);
          $entity->setWorksheet($fileName);
        }
        else {
          return;
        }

    }

    // public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    // {
    //     $entity = $args->getEntity();
    //
    //     $fileName = $entity->getSheet();
    //
    //     $entity->setSheet(new File($this->targetPath.'/'.$fileName));
    // }
}
```

The field is included in the sonata admin Admin as below:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->add('worksheet',FileType::class, array('label' => 'Inspection Worksheet', 'data_class' => null, 'required' => false))
}
```

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem? I#m facing the same at the moment.

Comment: I had to do a workaround which wasn't very pretty. Basically I check unit of work value. If the new value of the field is blank I restore the old value before saving